# Cannot use multiple radiogroups in react-materialize

Tags: reactjs, materialize

So, I am building an avatar creator for my application, and I have a Carousel that holds multiple RadioGroups, I can slide to the new radiogroup, but when I click on any of the other radio groups (except for the first one) and it will only target the value from the first one.

```
<Carousel options={{ fullWidth: true, indicators: true }} className="black-text center">
   <div>
      <RadioGroup
          name="hair"
          label="Hair Selection"
          value={this.state.avatar.topType}
          onChange={this.handleAvatarChange}
          options={[{ label: 'Eyepatch', value: 'Eyepatch' }, { label: 'Long 
          Hair', value: 'LongHairStraight2' }, { label: 'Medium Hair', value: 
          'LongHairNotTooLong' }, { label: 'Short Hair', value: 
          'ShortHairShortFlat' }, { label: 'Short Dreads', value: 
          'ShortHairDreads01' }, { label: 'Balding', value: 'ShortHairSides' 
           }]}
      />
     </div>
     <div>
         <RadioGroup
          name="hairColor"
          label="Hair Selection"
          value={this.state.avatar.hairColor}
          onChange={this.handleAvatarChange}
          options={[{ label: 'Brown', value: 'Brown' }, { label: 'Blonde', 
          value: 'Blonde' }, { label: 'Red', value: 
          'Red' }, { label: 'Gray', value: 
          'Gray' }, { label: 'Black', value: 
          'Black' }, { label: 'Auburn', value: 'Auburn' 
           }]}
      />
     </div>
</Carousel>
```

```
    handleAvatarChange = (event) => {
        let selection = event.target.value;
        let type = event.target.name;
        console.log(selection, 'event')
        console.log(type, 'type');
        let avatarCopy = { ...this.state.avatar };
        if (type === 'hair') {
            avatarCopy.topType = selection
            this.setState({ avatar: avatarCopy });
        } else if (type === 'hairColor') {
            avatarCopy.hairColor = selection;
            this.setState({ avatar: avatarCopy });
        }
    }
```

I expect that when I slide to the next slide on the carousel, that I can change the state based on the type that was passed back to my handleAvatarChange function. Instead, all of the slides are changing the values based on the first slide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the autogenerated id numbering for the options resets to 0 for each radiogroup, even if they are in the same DOM.
Therefore, each *n* input of the radio groups has the same id (`<input id="radio0" type="radio" value="1" checked="">`).

I have reported the bug [here](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/989).

As a workaround, I'm requesting an "id" prop, and if not found, concatenating the component's name to the index to build the id's.

```js
var RadioGroup = function RadioGroup(_ref) {
  var onChange = _ref.onChange,
      withGap = _ref.withGap,
      disabled = _ref.disabled,
      name = _ref.name,
      radioClassNames = _ref.radioClassNames,
      value = _ref.value,
      options = _ref.options;
  return _react.default.createElement(_react.default.Fragment, null, options.map(function (radioItem, idx) {
    return _react.default.createElement("label", {
      className: radioClassNames,
      htmlFor:  radioItem.id ? radioItem.id : "radio".concat(radioItem.name).concat(idx),
      key:  radioItem.id ? radioItem.id : "radio".concat(radioItem.name).concat(idx)
    }, _react.default.createElement("input", {
      id: radioItem.id ? radioItem.id : "radio".concat(radioItem.name).concat(idx),
      value: radioItem.value,
      type: "radio",
      checked: radioItem.value === value,
      name: name,
      onChange: onChange,
      disabled: disabled,
      className: (0, _classnames.default)({
        'with-gap': withGap
      })
    }), _react.default.createElement("span", null, radioItem.label));
  }));
};
```